# Why can't imshow show a matrix full of ones properly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

Here is a simple re-producable code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
img = np.ones((3,3))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.array([1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]).reshape(3,3))
```

It will give you images like below:

[image: image of matrix 1]

[image: image of matrix 2]

Even if you use

```py
plt.imshow(img.astype(float)) or
plt.imshow(img*255)
```

it is still the same image.

I just need Matplotlib to give me the first image as a yellow image just like the second image does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly use the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters of [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

> When using scalar data and no explicit *norm*, *vmin* and *vmax* define the data range that the colormap covers. By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data. *vmin*, *vmax* are ignored if the *norm* parameter is used.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
img = np.ones((3, 3))
plt.imshow(img, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]).reshape(3, 3))
plt.show()
```

For the second example, the data range is `[0 ... 1]`, so the colors are scaled with respect to that range by default. But, for the first example, the desired data range of `[0 ... 1]` can't be extracted from the data itself (all ones), such that you have to provide that information explicitly.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc3
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you! I did not realize that matplotlib actually tries to normalize the image based on the [min, max]...really thanks